# How to find all nodes that have no translation for specific language?

Tags: 8

I am looking for a programmatic way to find all nodes of language en that have no translation for language XY. Is there even a way to do that without raw sql? I tried using entityQuery but I cant get the negative condition get to work...

Comment: It's hard to query something which doesn't exists. I would array_diff() two queries.

Comment: @4uk4 i just got the same idea - thanks :)

Comment: Entity query can't do this, but SQL / DBquery can do it, either with a sub query `...where id not in (...subquery)...` or by outer-joining the node table on itself (then you can filter on the joined nid being null). But I wouldn't go the SQL route unless you are querying _really huge_ numbers of nodes.